# C# - Screen resolution Not Working With Selenium Chrome Web Driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chrome web driver (93.0.4577.63) with selenium (3.141.0) on chrome browser (93.0.4577.82).
What I'm trying to do is changing the screen resolution when I access a website , but it is not working.
My code is :

```
IWebDriver driver;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
            ChromeOptions op = new ChromeOptions();

            op.AddAdditionalCapability("screen-resolution", "-screenwidth 1024 -screenheight 768", true);
          
            op.AddArgument("incognito");
            op.AddArgument("--window-size=771,360");
            op.AddArgument("window-size=771,360");
            
           
            driver = new ChromeDriver(op);
            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://bestfirms.com/what-is-my-screen-resolution/");
          
         
         

        }
```

my main screen resolution is 1920X1080 . When I try to access a site to check if it changed to another resolution (771X360) it does not work.

can you please point me at what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

**Edit** : I have also tried

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(771, 360);
```

still no luck :(

Comment: Did you set the window position first?

Comment: I did not actually , is it important to do so ?

Comment: I tried driver.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 300); still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
ChromeOptions op = new ChromeOptions();
op.AddArgument("--incognito");
op.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
op.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(op);
```

Possibly your script needed `--incognito` not only `incognito`.

**PS** If the above one work then, You can change this `--window-size=1920,1080` to `--window-size=771,360`

Comment: Hello , I tried your solution it is still not working

Comment: when you tried with `op.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");` did it launch in full screen mode.

Comment: yes it launched in full screen like not exactly full screen but 1920x1080 resolution

Comment: 771 should also work.

Comment: The size of chrome window changes but inside the browser ``` window.screen.height; window.screen.width; ``` remain 1920x1080.